# Deploying an ARM Template for Ocotpus Deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, octopus-deploy, azure-bicep

I have an IaC deployment implemented as a GitHub action, and I need to move it to Octopus Deploy.

My first azure arm template that creates a resource group.  However, the built-in *Deploy an Azure Resource Manager template* step requires a resource group when I am setting it up. I don't have a resource group; my ARM is creating it.

My deployment will do more than create a resource group. I also have ARMs to create all the resources inside the group. For these, I can't specify the resource group when setting up the process because it is creat as part of the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

On the ARM step, turn on the Custom Deployment Scripts (via the Configure Features button).

In the pre-deploy script add the following script:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $name -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;

if ($notPresent) {
  New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $name -Location "WestUS" 
}
```

Not tested, taken from https://octopus.com/blog/dynamic-infrastructure#the-deployment-process